# How to find the hierarchy levels of a person(employee,manager etc.) using graphframes in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, breadth-first-search, graphframes

I have a graph frame with vertices and edges as below. I am running this on pyspark in jupyter notebook.

```
vertices = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
      ("12345", "Alice", "Employee"),
      ("15789", "Bob", "Employee"),
      ("13467", "Charlie", "Manager"),
      ("14890", "David", "Director"),
      ("17737", "Fanny", "CEO")], ["id", "name", "title"])

    edges = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
      ("12345", "13467", "works"),
      ("15789", "13467", "works"),
      ("13467", "14890", "works"),
      ("14890", "17737", "works"),
    ], ["src", "dst", "relationship"])
```

I need to find the hierarchical paths of each emp_id up to the highest level(which is the CEO in this case). I am trying the bfs approach and so far I am successful in getting the path for only one emp_id.
Below is my code.

```
g = GraphFrame(vertices,edges)
result = g.bfs(fromExpr = "id == '12345'", toExpr = "title == 'CEO'", edgeFilter = "relationship == 'works'", maxPathLength = 5)
result.show(5,False)
```

Output:

```
+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|from                  |e0                 |v1                     |e1                 |v2                    |e2                 |to               |
+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|[12345,Alice,Employee]|[12345,13467,works]|[13467,Charlie,Manager]|[13467,14890,works]|[14890,David,Director]|[14890,17737,works]|[17737,Fanny,CEO]|
+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

I can store this information in a variable and extract using the `collect()` method.I want to loop through all the id's from the vertices which have a path to the CEO and write it to a dataframe. If anyone is familiar with graphframes can you please help me with this? I have tried looking into other solutions but none are working in my case.

Expected Output:

```
+-------+--------------------------+
|user_id|path                      |
+-------+--------------------------+
|12345  |12345->13467->14890->17737|
|15789  |15789->13467->14890->17737|
|13467  |13467->14890->17737       |
|14890  |14890->17737              |
|17737  |17737                     |
+-------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450917/build-a-hierarchy-from-a-relational-data-set-using-pyspark) for your question, and tidied up the result of that answer to get your desired output. Note that you need to interchange 'src' and 'dst' in the `edges` dataframe for that answer to work, but I think with some effort in modifying that answer, the `edges` dataframe can be used in its original form...

```py
from graphframes import GraphFrame
from graphframes.lib import Pregel
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

vertices = spark.createDataFrame([
      ("12345", "Alice", "Employee"),
      ("15789", "Bob", "Employee"),
      ("13467", "Charlie", "Manager"),
      ("14890", "David", "Director"),
      ("17737", "Fanny", "CEO")], ["id", "name", "title"])

edges = spark.createDataFrame([
      ("12345", "13467", "works"),
      ("15789", "13467", "works"),
      ("13467", "14890", "works"),
      ("14890", "17737", "works"),
    ], ["dst", "src", "relationship"])

g = GraphFrame(vertices,edges)

vertColSchema = StructType()\
      .add("dist", DoubleType())\
      .add("node", StringType())\
      .add("path", ArrayType(StringType(), True))

def vertexProgram(vd, msg):
    if msg == None or vd.__getitem__(0) < msg.__getitem__(0):
        return (vd.__getitem__(0), vd.__getitem__(1), vd.__getitem__(2))
    else:
        return (msg.__getitem__(0), vd.__getitem__(1), msg.__getitem__(2))

vertexProgramUdf = F.udf(vertexProgram, vertColSchema)

def sendMsgToDst(src, dst):
    srcDist = src.__getitem__(0)
    dstDist = dst.__getitem__(0)
    if srcDist < (dstDist - 1):
        return (srcDist + 1, src.__getitem__(1), src.__getitem__(2) + [dst.__getitem__(1)])
    else:
        return None

sendMsgToDstUdf = F.udf(sendMsgToDst, vertColSchema)

def aggMsgs(agg):
    shortest_dist = sorted(agg, key=lambda tup: tup[1])[0]
    return (shortest_dist.__getitem__(0), shortest_dist.__getitem__(1), shortest_dist.__getitem__(2))

aggMsgsUdf = F.udf(aggMsgs, vertColSchema)

result = (
    g.pregel.withVertexColumn(
        colName = "vertCol",

        initialExpr = F.when(
            F.col("id") == 17737,
            F.struct(F.lit(0.0), F.col("id"), F.array(F.col("id")))
        ).otherwise(
            F.struct(F.lit(float("inf")), F.col("id"), F.array(F.lit("")))
        ).cast(vertColSchema),

        updateAfterAggMsgsExpr = vertexProgramUdf(F.col("vertCol"), Pregel.msg())
    )
    .sendMsgToDst(sendMsgToDstUdf(F.col("src.vertCol"), Pregel.dst("vertCol")))
    .aggMsgs(aggMsgsUdf(F.collect_list(Pregel.msg())))
    .setMaxIter(5)    ## This should be greater than the max depth of the graph
    .setCheckpointInterval(1)
    .run()
)

df = result.select("vertCol.node", "vertCol.path").repartition(1)
df.show()
+-----+----------------------------+
|node |path                        |
+-----+----------------------------+
|12345|[17737, 14890, 13467, 12345]|
|15789|[17737, 14890, 13467, 15789]|
|13467|[17737, 14890, 13467]       |
|14890|[17737, 14890]              |
|17737|[17737]                     |
+-----+----------------------------+

final = df.select('node', F.concat_ws('->', F.reverse('path')).alias('path'))
final.show()
+-----+--------------------------+
|node |path                      |
+-----+--------------------------+
|12345|12345->13467->14890->17737|
|15789|15789->13467->14890->17737|
|13467|13467->14890->17737       |
|14890|14890->17737              |
|17737|17737                     |
+-----+--------------------------+
```