# Using GraphFrames (Scala) to compute hierarchy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graphframes

I have a dataframe below:

```
employee_id|employee_name|manager_employee_id|
----------------------------------------------
    1           eric (ceo)      1
    2           edward          1
    3           john            1
    4           james           2
    5           ella            4
```

I would like to use spark (scala) graphframe logic to achieve the following:

```
employee_id|employee_name|manager_employee_id|level|hierarchy
-------------------------------------------------------------
    1           eric            1                0    /1
    2           edward          1                1    /1/2
    3           john            1                1    /1/3
    4           james           2                2    /1/2/4
    5           ella            3                3    /1/2/4/5
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is more or less related to [this](https://dzone.com/articles/processing-hierarchical-data-using-spark-graphx-pr).

The only modification required at your end will be aggregating the messages to get the complete hierarchy .
For that part you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450917/build-a-hierarchy-from-a-relational-data-set-using-pyspark).

A combination of above two will get you the desired results.