# Pyspkark / Spark SQL Flatten Parent Child Table With Unknown Level of Hierarchy

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with two columns (Parent and Child), which have unknown levels of granularity / hierarchy, as shown below:

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |
| C | D |
| B | BB |
| X | Y |
| Y | Z |

And the result should be something like, using pyspark dataframe functions or sparkSQL:

| level1 | level2 | level3 | level4 | granularity_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D | 4 |
| A | B | BB | Null | 3 |
| X | Y | Z | Null | 3 |

Thanks & Regards

Comment: another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450917/build-a-hierarchy-from-a-relational-data-set-using-pyspark

Comment: Thank you for your comment. They might seem similar but unfortunately they are note. Because here in this case we don't know neither the highest nor the lowest level of granularity. Regards,

Comment: I think mck is right, what do you mean?

Comment: How about this https://sqlandhadoop.com/how-to-implement-recursive-queries-in-spark/ and then apply a pivot or similar?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?