# Create hierarchy table/dataframe in Spark or SQL

Tags: sql, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have the following dataframe that contains all the data I need.
The thing is, each child can be found in the parent column with their own children

- 1000584 is Top level
- 4003773 is Level 1
- 1252665 is Level 2
  *1321212 is Level 3

[image]

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

Comment: Check this answer for a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62521978/11713502

Comment: Can you give any sample code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use the self join but seems it's much complex than that.  hierarchy = combinedDF.alias('Parrent').join(combinedDF.alias('Child'), col("Parrent.MATNR") == col("Child.IDNRK"), 'left')

Comment: @TusharPatil That solution was not what I needed. I managed to solve it. I had to create some custom methods in Spark to do the trick. But thanks!